# Create chance function in rpg game

Tags: algorithm, random

I am creating a server-side RPG game that has a chance system. for example, the player has a 30% chance when hit target stuns the enemy and 70% percent to 35% more damage.

so I come with this solution.

```
//'s' as stuns and 'd' as more damage;
array a = ['s', 's', 's', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'];
int chance = random(0, 9);
print a[chance];
```

but the above solution has a problem first it only works with an Integer number and another is that only work with a number that can be divided by 10.

for example, the above function that's not going to work with 25% or 0.1% chance as input.

> ** Warning: The code above is not a language. it just is written algorithm**

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: I have an answer, but this looks like a mash of several languages, and I'm not sure what to write my answer in.

Comment: @carcigenicate the language doesn't matter!

Comment: Please don't tag a question with a language if the language isn't actually relevant

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, it is relevant but at this point, I don't care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a large number, and check if that random number is less than a number representing the percentage.

For example, to have a 30% chance (I'm going to use a lower bound of 1 to make the code simpler, and I'm assuming both bounds are inclusive):

```java
int chance = random(1, 10) // 1 - 10

if (chance <= 3):
    // The 30% chance was met (3 / 10 == 30%)
```

or

```java
int chance = random(1, 100) // 1 - 100

if (chance <= 37):
    // A 37% chance was met (37 / 100 == 37%)
```

or, for float chances, generate from a value over 100:

```java
int chance = random(1, 1000) // 1 - 1000

if (chance <= 123):
    // A 12.3% was met (123 / 1000 == 12.3%)
```

Add more 0s to the random generator to get more precision. 1000 for numbers to one decimal place, 10000 for numbers to two decimal places...

The number in the condition is a percentage of the max number possibly produced by the generator.

Of course, this assumes a uniform generator.

Comment: thanks, but it has another problem with float chance like a 0.1% chance.

Comment: @Milad See the new last example